# Precisamos de auditoria para a ferramenta de auditoria?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, auditoria

### *Rant mode on*

Acredito que uma parcela significativa das pessoas que passam algum tempo moderando o site já viveu alguma experiência frustrante com as auditorias de moderação.

Existem muitas perguntas que receberam *upvotes / downvotes* por receber. Além do fator "voto de ocasião", temos ainda mudanças "ideológicas" do site ([vide discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32150346#32150346)) que invalidam decisões anteriores.

Enquanto entendo que não há como implementar auditorias perfeitas (e sei que o algoritmo de auditoria ainda está sendo calibrado), acredito que há espaço para melhorias nessa frente.

Partindo do pressuposto que a hipótese testada pela auditoria seja "O usuário que está moderando não está prestando atenção no que está fazendo", devemos tentar evitar ao máximo tanto [erros do tipo I](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erro_do_tipo_I) quanto [erros do tipo II](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erro_do_tipo_II). Se a ideia da auditoria é garantir que os usuários prestem atenção naquilo que estão fazendo é importante evitar perguntas que induzam ao erro. Não queremos usuários que estão prestando atenção falhando testes de auditoria da mesma forma que não queremos usuários que não estão prestando atenção passando na auditoria.

### Ilustrando o problema

Eis o último exemplo de auditoria em que falhei:

[image: Exemplo de auditoria que falhou]

Não é que [a pergunta em questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138448/100) não seja "salvável". Porém a escolha de palavras do OP foi confusa. No meu caso foi difícil entender que por "exibir a linha" o que o OP realmente queria fazer era incluir `double tInicio` na compilação.

Meu instinto natural nesse caso seria votar para fechar a pergunta como "não está clara o suficiente".

Na sequência minha intenção era deixar um comentário pedindo para o OP clarificar a pergunta. Por sinal [o @bigown fez o mesmo em julho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138448/comando-do-compilador-gcc-para-exibir-ifdef#comment287064_138448), ou seja, me parece que meus instintos estavam corretos (ou ao menos tão errados quanto os instintos de outro moderador experiente).

Enfim, nesse caso realmente a "Auditoria de análise falhou". Porém não acho que minha análise falhou (isso é, continuo achando que existem problemas com a pergunta).

### Reação típica: Vamos driblar a auditoria!

É claro que, sabendo que eventualmente posso estar sendo auditado, é possível contornar a auditoria seguindo alguns passos mecânicos:

1. Abrir as perguntas em uma nova aba/janela
2. Verificar o número real de votos
3. Se número de votos na pergunta real é diferente do número de votos na janela de auditoria então tome a mesma decisão que a comunidade tomou na pergunta real.

Mas isso não significa que eu estou prestando mais atenção do que antes no que estou fazendo. Pelo contrário, estou adotando passos mecânicos para fazer com que o sistema de auditoria pare de me atucanar.

### Sugestão para melhorar a auditoria

Meu ponto aqui é: Há algo que possa ser feito para melhorar o sistema de auditoria e minimizar esse tipo de coisa?

Minha sugestão é incluir um link "Eu discordo da auditoria, acredito que existam problemas reais com a pergunta/resposta" quando alguém falhar na auditoria.

Perguntas marcadas dessa maneira poderiam cair em uma fila de moderação e, com um número suficiente de votos descartaríamos perguntas problemáticas dos testes. A votação nesse caso impediria que usuários abusassem do mecanismo de "auditoria da auditoria".

O que vocês acham? Alguém tem uma sugestão melhor? Outras pessoas estão satisfeitas com o sistema de auditoria ou vocês possuem mais histórias de horror para contar?

Comment: Bom que o detalhe fundamental foi "previsto" ;) _A votação nesse caso impediria que usuários abusassem do mecanismo de "auditoria da auditoria"_ - Importante para evitar o feedback causar mais dano do que solução.

Comment: Não vou responder porque não tenho uma resposta. E também tenho minhas dúvidas se não é duplicata de http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4993/101 que já conhece. O que eu entendo (e os moderadores tem acesso à estatísticas avançadas sobre a auditoria) é que isso é feito mais para barrar o *greasemonkey* humano. Você não acredita como tem usuários assim. Se ele se der um pouco de trabalho para burlar o sistema, já é alguma coisa. Não sei se todo mundo sabia fazer isso, agora aprendeu. Concordo que ela pode ser melhorada, eu mesmo discordo dela várias vezes e tem casos patéticos.

Comment: Oi @bigown. O Bacco já tinha me mostrado a pergunta acima. Decidi abrir essa pergunta aqui como uma sugestão de ferramenta para auditar a auditoria. Minha impressão é que a frustração na pergunta acima tinha mais a ver com desperdício de tempo escrevendo comentários em testes... Ainda que boa parte dos melhores usuários que conheço no site tenham aproveitado para reclamar nos comentários da pergunta. De qualquer forma, estou curioso para saber se outras pessoas acham que esse tipo de funcionalidade seria útil ou se estou viajando.

Comment: "Não sei se todo mundo sabia fazer isso, agora aprendeu". Mea culpa, perdão. Dito isso, não sei o quão significativa é a intersecção de *greasemonkey* humano com usuários do meta (se fiz um estrago grande pode mandar a pergunta com todo o histórico para o Zebeléo e eu pergunto de novo sem mencionar o *workaround*).

Comment: Falei mais pra encher o saco. Eu acho que se a pessoa se deu ao trabalho de abrir a aba para ver como tá já passou na auditoria. É o melhor que ela pode conseguir. Algumas pessoas perderam temporariamente o privilégio de análise de fila e tem uns 2 ou 3 que estão pedindo para perder.

Comment: Eu já usava "o abrir outra aba" antes de haver auditorias, quando tinha dúvidas.

Comment: Isso ai eu também já fazia em casos de perguntas mais antigas, pra ver se tinha algo nos comentários que mudasse minha escolha antes do fechamento, não considero como uma forma de burlar a auditoria. O que irrita é ter que fazer isso pra todos os casos, ou quando sua convicção simplesmente é rejeitada pela auditoria, com esse "falhou".

Comment: Pois é. Eu sempre tive esse costume também (por isso "descobri" como fazer isso). Dito isso o ponto é que dá para burlar a auditoria 100% no automático. Enquanto isso as perguntas ruins de auditoria eventualmente são irritantes para pessoas que não estão 100% no modo automático. Eu acho que precisamos fazer alguma coisa em relação a elas.

Comment: Esse assunto é recorrente. Lembro que postei no início do ano: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4885/auditoria-na-fila-de-an%C3%A1lise  No início foi negativado, achei que estavam rejeitando e deixei quieto... não quis mais falar nada..

Comment: Encontrei outro que eu nem sabia que existia, postou poucos dias antes de mim. inclusive o título é idêntico mas como está com muitos negativos, acho que na época eu não tinha acesso: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4885/auditoria-na-fila-de-an%C3%A1lise

Comment: Aqui mais um,..http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4993/teste-da-fila-de-an%C3%A1lise-insira-aqui-o-seu-palavr%C3%A3o-preferido  Felizmente enfim, alguém com mais de 15 mil pontos vem reclamar desse recurso.. Só assim para darem atenção..

Comment: Sendo mais objetivo, desde a época que falei do assunto, em Fevereiro de 2016, eu simplesmente parei de acessar as análises.. É muito frustrante a perda de tempo que a "auditoria" (pegadinha do malandro!) causa as pessoas que estão ali doando o seu tempo. Eu entendo que é útil para evitar abusos. Acredito que seja muito mais funcional num ambiente de maior movimento como o SO-en.. mas aqui no SO-pt, não sei dizer.

Comment: Mas tem um jeito de "burlar". Uma técnica para driblar a "pegadinha" é abrir o link da pergunta numa nova janela então poderá ter uma noção apenas observando se está fechada para análise ou aberta. Se estiver aberta é uma pegadinha. rsrs.. mas mesmo assim, já não tenho mais motivação para analisar nada.. isso é trabalhar de graça e ser feito de bobo..

Comment: Oi Daniel, em maior ou menor grau acho que todos nós tivemos problemas com a auditoria (O que de nenhuma forma tira o mérito do mecanismo. Realmente tem muita gente moderando no automático). Quanto a reação da comunidade às reclamações, enquanto de fato participar do site ativamente aumenta seu poder de alcance / visibilidade. Acho que negativações no meta tem também muito a ver com o tom da pergunta. Digamos que nerds em média são Vulcanians: Demonstrar descontentamento em tom moderado é aceitável, sugerir melhorias é melhor ainda. O resto costuma ser ignorado ou combatido :)